# Calling the correct function specialization using a vector of variants

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-specialization, variant

I have a vector of variants and several fully specialized functions. Now I want to call the correct function depending on the elements of my vector without having to check each individual element (which is what I am currently doing with the help of a second vector). I don't even need to get the values inside the variant vector, I just need to get to the types.

Does anyone know of some sort of template trickery to help me? Or was I correct in thinking there is no more elegant way of doing this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

using valType = std::variant<int, unsigned long, float, double>;

// Base Case
template<typename... Ts>
void func(Ts...);

// Full Specializations
template<>
void func(unsigned long);
template<>
void func(double, double);
template<>
void func(float, double);

int main()
{
    std::vector<valType> values;
    // In theory there is a second vector which encodes the types into ints:
    // std::vector<int> types
    values.emplace_back( float{} );
    // types.emplace_back(2)
    values.emplace_back( double{} );
    // types.emplace_back(3)
    
    // What I currently do is check if types[0] == 2 and types[1] == 3, 
    // so I know to call func(float, double).
    // Is there a more elegant way figuring out I want to call func(float, double)?
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)? (look at the second example with overloads)

Comment: How are you determining the number of parameters? Is it always 2? Why not put them in a `std::tuple` to make the parameters "belong together"? (a vector of tuples)

Comment: You mean `std::visit([](auto x, auto y) { func(x, y); }, values[0], values[1]);`?

Comment: @super I did but I'll have another look in case I overlooked something. 
It is not always two elements, that's why I thought tuples were not fitting. But I'll  also look into it in case I oversaw something. Thanks.

Comment: @Clutterhead So how are you hoping to know if it's a 1, 2, 3 or 4 parameter function without looking at the types first to determine it? Packing the arguments in grouped tuples would solve that for you. One tuple for one function call, the tuple can hold any number of elements.

Comment: `std::holds_alternative` is also there.

Comment: @康桓瑋 This seems interesting, I did not realize it was possible to give multiple variants into visit.

Comment: @super How would I put the values into the tuples if I only get the values one by one and not all at once?

Comment: @Clutterhead You can update values in the tuple as they come in. Or you can wait until you have enough to know where they belong. Depends on some of the circumstances here that's not clarified yet by your question, and probably should be before a good answer is possible.